# Adding node in linked list to first pos in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to make linked list and it already workes with one exception - adding new node to first position.

My node:

```cpp
struct MyNode
{
   string s;
   int i;
   MyNode* pointer;
}
```

Linked list:

```cpp
private:
   MyNode first;
   int count;

public:
  //methods
```

I had two ideas how to add new node to first position but none of them worked.
The first one:

```cpp
void Add(Node* node, int index)
{
   if (index == 1)
   {
      node->pointer = &first;
      first = *node;
   }
}
```

The node pointer points to itself and all other nodes are lost.

The second idea:

```cpp
void Add(Node* node, int index)
{
   if (index == 1)
   {
      Node n2 = first;
      first = *node;
      first.pointer = &n2;
   }
}
```

which works fine at first but as soon as the program leaves the if, the node that was supposed to be second loses its string data (integer not for some reason).

Is it possible to write method to add node to first position without having to remake the structure of my list (it would break all other methods I wrote)?

Edit: Minimal reproducable example:

```cpp
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    string forename{};
    string surname{};
    int age{};
    Person* pointer{};
};

class linked_list
{
private:
    Person first;
    int count = 0;

    Person* GetPointer(int index)
    {
        Person* current = &first;
        Person* next = first.pointer;
        if (index == 1) return &first;
        for (int i = 1; (i < index) && (next->pointer != NULL); i++)
        {
            current = next;
            next = next->pointer;
        }
        return current;
    }

public:
    linked_list()
    {
        first.forename = "dummy";
        first.surname = "dummy";
        first.age = 0;
    }
    void Add(Person* p, int index)
    {
        if ((index < 1) || (index > count + 1))
        {
            throw 0;
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            Person p2 = first;
            first = *p;
            first.pointer = &p2;
            /*p->pointer = &first;
            first = *p;*/
        }
        else if (index == count + 1)
        {
            p->pointer = NULL;
            Person* p2 = GetPointer(index);
            p2->pointer->pointer = p;
        }
        else
        {
            p->pointer = GetPointer(index);
            Person* p2 = GetPointer(index - 1);
            p2->pointer = p;
        }
        count++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    linked_list l;
    Person p;
    p.age = 35;
    p.forename = "John";
    p.surname = "Smith";
    l.Add(&p, 1);
}
```

Comment: `MyNode* pointer;` should be initialized properly before any usage. Also provide a [mcve] as required here, when demonstrating problems with your specific code.

Comment: `first.pointer = &n2;` certainly isn't going to end well. that's storing the address of an automatic local variable `n2` that literally expires one line later. That address is worthless.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added the example

Comment: How would you represent an **empty** list? It is wrong to assume there must be a `first` person. It is ugly to have to initialise it with age 0 and "dummy" name just to indicate it isn't *really* an entry of this list. This is bad practice. You should not look for a solution that will keep this pattern. You need to completely redo this, and stop having this `first`. You need to represent an empty list with a null pointer. Trying to keep that `first` in a working solution will just confirm a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that need to be done.

All variables must be initiliazed. That is utmost important. You can do this also dirctely in the class definition. Example:

```
struct MyNode {
   string s{};
   int i{};
   MyNode* pointer{};
};
```

The [uniform value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) with `{}` is availabe since 10 years. It will initilize the string to an empty string, "i" to 0 and "pointer" to `nullptr`.

In the context of a singly linked list often the variable name "next" is used instead of pointer.

Then, what you did correctly, Nodes are parts of a linked list. In object oriented terms you would say a linked list "has a" node. We call it a "has a"-relation.

But also here, you would use a different name.

"MyNode first;" would become "MyNode *head;" because, the signly linked list only needs a pointer to the first node in the list.

If you want to add values to a linked list, then you would create dynamically a new node, assign the value to the node and then add the node to the linked list.

We need to differentiate between adding the first node or adding a node to a list that already contains other nodes.

And empty linked list is easy to identify. The "head" pointer will be a `nullptr` and then you can simply assign the new node's pointer to "head".

In case that there are already element in the singly linked list, then you must find the last element in the chain of nodes, by starting at head and then following all "next" pointer until this is "nullptr". Then you add the new node to this next pointer.

In order for you to get a better understanding, you may study the attached code (maybe a little bit advanced, but anyway):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

// Very simple implementation of a forward list
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

    // The node
    struct Node {
        T data{};     // Data. Would normally be a templated argument
        Node* next{};   // And the pointer to the next node

        Node(const T& i, Node* n = nullptr) : data(i), next(n) {}; // Simple constructor to set a value and next pointer
    };

    Node* head{};       // This is the start of the list
    // It would be advisable to have a tail pointer. We use the more inefficient approach here
    Node* getLast() const { Node* n{ head }; while (n and n->next) n = n->next; return n; }

public:
    // Constructor / Destructor --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~SinglyLinkedList() { clear(); }

    // Default constuctor
    SinglyLinkedList() {}   // Default
    // From an initialization list
    SinglyLinkedList(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear();  for (const T& i : il) push_back(i); } // From initializer list
    // Copy constructor
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }
    // Move constructor. Will steal the elements from the other 
    SinglyLinkedList(SinglyLinkedList&& other) noexcept { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }
    // Assignment operator
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }
    // Move assignment operator 
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (SinglyLinkedList&& other) { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Housekeeping --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { Node* tmp{ head }; while (tmp) { Node* toDelete{ tmp }; tmp = tmp->next; delete toDelete; } head = nullptr; }
    int empty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    int size() const { int k{}; Node* n{ head }; while (n) { ++k; n = n->next; } return k; }

    // Modify content --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_back(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); Node* l = getLast(); if (l) l->next = n; else head = n; }
    void push_front(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); n->next = head; head = n; };
    void pop_back() { // This is a little bit more difficult in a singly linked list
        if (head) {
            Node* n{ head }, * previous{};
            while (n and n->next) {
                previous = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
            delete n;
            if (previous)
                previous->next = nullptr;
            else
                head->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
    void pop_front() { if (head) { Node* tmp = head->next; delete head; head = tmp; } }

    // Access elements --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    T back() const { Node* n = getLast(); return n ? n->data : 0; }
    T front() const { return head ? head->data : 0; };

    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {                           // Local class for iterator
        Node* iter{};                           // Iterator is basically a pointer to the node
        Node* head{};

        // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Constructor
        iterator() {}
        iterator(Node* n, Node* h) : iter(n), head(h) {}

        // Dereferencing
        reference operator *() const { return iter->data; }
        pointer operator ->() const { return &iter->data; }

        // Aithmetic operations
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter) iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator& operator --() { Node* tmp = head; while (tmp and tmp->next != this->iter) tmp = tmp->next; iter = tmp;  return *this; }
        iterator operator ++(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; ++* this; return temp; }
        iterator operator --(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; --* this; return temp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp; }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this; };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp; }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this; };

        // Comparison
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; }
        bool operator == (const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; }
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return iter < other.iter; }
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return iter <= other.iter; }
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return iter > other.iter; }
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return iter >= other.iter; }

        // Difference. Also complicated, because no random access
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const {
            difference_type result{};
            Node* n{ iter };
            while (n and n != other.iter) {
                ++result;
                n = n->next;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    // Begin and end function to initialize an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(nullptr, head); }

    // Functions typcical for forward lists ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Easy, becuase we can operate form the current iterator and do not need the "previous" element
    iterator insertAfter(iterator& pos, const T& i) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* n = new Node(i, pos.iter->next);
            pos.iter->next = n;
            result.iter = n;
        }
        return result;
    }
    iterator eraseAfter(iterator& pos) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* tmp = pos.iter->next->next;
            delete pos.iter->next;
            pos.iter->next = tmp;
            result.iter = pos.iter->next;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
// Test/Driver Code
int main() {

    // Example for initilizer list
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sllbase{ 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    // Show move constructor
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sll(std::move(sllbase));

    // Add some values in the front
    sll.push_front(4);
    sll.push_front(3);
    sll.push_front(2);
    sll.push_front(1);

    // Delete 1st element (Number 1)
    sll.pop_front();
    // Delete last element
    sll.pop_back();

    // Use a std::algorithm on our custom linked list. Works because we have an interator
    SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator iter = std::find(sll.begin(), sll.end(), 8);
    ++iter;
    --iter;

    // Now add an element after 8
    iter = sll.insertAfter(iter, 88);
    // And delete the 9
    iter = sll.eraseAfter(iter);

    // Use range based for loop. Works because, we have iterators
    for (int i : sll)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    // Reverse Output
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::reverse_iterator<SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator> riter = std::make_reverse_iterator(sll.end());
    std::reverse_iterator<SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator> riterEnd = std::make_reverse_iterator(sll.begin());

    for (; riter != riterEnd; ++riter)
        std::cout << *riter << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Initializing content of the nodes was a good idea, but it did not help. Also I know I could change the head to a pointer, but it would break all my other methods, thats why I asked in the question if it would be possible without other changes.